# jQuery print a specifc div with background color for each th element of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I am working on a print button to print a div with all what does include.

Here is my script:

```
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("print_div");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);

  var css = "table, td, th { \n"+
  "    border: 1px solid black; \n"+
  "    txt-align:justify; \n"+
  "} \n"+
  "th {  \n"+
  "    background-color: #7a7878; \n"+
  "    text-align:center; \n"+
  "}";
   var div = $("<div />", {
    html: '&shy;<style>' + css + '</style>'
    }).appendTo( newWin.document.body);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
```

When I click on the print button: I barely see this:

[image]

And then in a matter of a second, the print screen show this:

[image]

The original background color is blue instead of dark grey, but even the dark grey is not showing in the print screen.

I tried this, and yes the form changed, but still can't see any background color:

```
$("#print_div").show();
$("#print_div").show().append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='../css/bootstrap.min.css' media='print' />");
window.print();
```

Most of SO similar answered questions still didn't work for me.

Comment: have you tried custom styling using `@media print { ... }`.

Comment: No I didn't. How to do that

Comment: just directly write the styles you want to show in print view inside the `@media print { ... }`. [Example here](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/)

Answer (score 1):

try this instead

```
 var css = "@media print {" +
  "table, td, th { \n"+
  "    border: 1px solid black; \n"+
  "    txt-align:justify; \n"+
  "} \n"+
  "th {  \n"+
  "    background-color: #7a7878; \n"+
  "    text-align:center; \n"+
  "}" +
  "}";
var style =$('<style>').html(css);
style.appendTo(newWin.document.head)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn setting on to print background color.

For example in Chrome browser, follow these steps:

1. Press **Ctrl + p** to bring print window
2. On left pane, click on **More settings...**
3. Check **Background graphics**

[image]

### Edge Browser

1. Click on three dots at top right corner

[image]

2. **Open with Internet Explorer**
3. Gear icon > Print > Page Setup
   [image]
4. Check **Print Background Colors and Images** 
   [image]

### Internet Explorer

Follow from step 3 as for **Edge** browser

Comment: can I apply this using script ?